# Unable to Unmarshal a payload with spaces in values

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I am using Golang to read an XML response.  I am unable to read values with spaces properly.

Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5825288

Is there a way to have xml.Unmarshal trim the value from `<result>` and then treat it as an int?

I.e.

```
<result>1<result> // no spaces, is marshalled correctly.  The resulting value in the struct is 1
```

but

```
<result> 1 </result>  // with spaces, is marshalled incorrectly as an int.  The resulting value in the struct for result is 0.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

even in xml " 1 " this is a string and not a int, 
the parser cant parse this string to an int. so 0 is just the default int value,

if you change your code to :

```
err:= xml.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &mt)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

you will see that there was an error during parsing
if your xml could have " 1 " as value, i recommend to use a string in your struct. 
or if there is a chance, tell the creator of the xml to only use int and not strings, where int are expected

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I feed this struct to a mongodb collection so changing the field to a string would require some legwork (which might be OK).   I can send a note to the XML creator to ensure to only use ints in certain fields.  If neither are possible, I guess I would have to vet the payload before unmarshaling it? I  wish I could force a Trim() then a ParseInt() on a field.

Comment: if you want to trim one special node inside the xml tree, i guess then you will already write your own xml parser, but this is is only capable to parse this special xml nothing else, a better work around would be to create a proxy struct, this proxy structs hold your xml struct internal, and all the public fields will just operate on the internal fields. and the result field will in your case then pare the string from xml struct into an int